# How to post base64 png in <meta property="og:image" >?

Tags: javascript, facebook, graph, share, facebook-opengraph

I want share a base64 png file in meta og:image property. I try but its not working.

How can i do this?

`<meta property="og:image" content="base64file">`

Comment: You can also give source url of image.. ? if you using any programming language like php java pls mention it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What attempts have you made? For help, see “[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)”, and here for “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: That is not possible. Facebook expects this value to be an HTTP(S) URL.